# Systrace on android emulator

Tags: android, systrace

I am trying to use systrace on an android 4.2 (avd 17) emulator

I have enabled usb debuggimg and activated webview in the tracing options and folloed this guide here http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Q8m9sHdyXnE#t=31m15s

But when I attempt to start tracing using ./systrace.py in android tools directory I see the following output

```
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_wakeup/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_frequency/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_idle/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_clock: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/workqueue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_enter/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_exit/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_issue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_complete/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on: No such file or directory (2)
error: unable to start trace
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_wakeup/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_frequency/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_clock: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/workqueue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_enter/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_exit/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_issue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_complete/enable: No such file or directory (2)
unable to start tracing
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb: No such file or directory (2)
```

Anyone know what I need to do to get tracing working ?

Comment: I think this answer has the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618755/failed-to-use-systrace-in-jelly-bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systrace does not support on emulator. it support only for devices.

more details:

[Unable to run systrace tool on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167626/unable-to-run-systrace-tool-on-android-emulator)

[Error running systrace tool in ADB using a Jelly Bean 4.1 emulator on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300773/error-running-systrace-tool-in-adb-using-a-jelly-bean-4-1-emulator-on-windows-7)

For devices Update you sdk to the latest version.

the systrace file path is `android-sdk\tools\systrace\systrace.py`. latest android 4.2+ `android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\systrace.py`.

root and remount the device using following command.

```
adb root
adb remount
```