# Unable to run systrace tool on android emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

Systrace tool which is used for performnce analysis of android devices are not getting executed on android emulator in ubuntu

I have tried below ways for the same but i end up with same problem

1.First of all I tried to mount /sys/kernel/debug then its readonly file system message comes
.So I am not able to create the same
2.Tried to create new kernel image kernel-qmeu image with latest goldfish source code and replaced at system images place of sdk,but the emulator fails to boot.
3.Editing init.rc and adding permissions for /sys/kernel/debug and recreated the ramdisk.img,emulator boots but it still hasnt have the debugfs at /sys/kernel
4.I tried replacing new kernel image with debugfs support(through make menuconfig) and ramdisk.img with debugfs permissions.But emulator fails to boot.

Kindly help me in this concern.
feel free to shoot back in case of any more clarifications

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300773/error-running-systrace-tool-in-adb-using-a-jelly-bean-4-1-emulator-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Google does not support the systrace tool in the emulator. You will need to get a Jelly Bean device that does support systrace. The Google Nexus devices seem to, and the Samsung GS3 does. My Motorola Droid RAZR M does not (so far at least). Good luck!

Comment: yes it supports.We need to enabled debugfs full support in emulator.I can successfully run systrace on emulator now.Thank you

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you enabled full debugfs support in the emulator? I'm assuming you recompiled from AOSP source code? Or perhaps found an .img file somewhere that had it enabled? I tried the simple approach of the mount command (didn't work).

Comment: Basic Needfuls to run Systrace are below :
1.Systrace needs debugfs support,which is a simple to use RAM based fs used for debugging purpose.It enables user to debug kernel
2.Setup complete ftrace support
3. Python with zlib support : python has to be built with other libraries such as sqlite,bzip2, libffi,openssl along with zlib to get complete zllib support as these are libraries are interlinked
4. Chromium browser is recommended to view the html display of traces.
Thank you